# How to avoid dismissing my progress dialog when the user touches the screen?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android project which displays a progress dialog when the user downloads a file.

But when the user touches the screen, the progress dialog is dismissed without waiting the 100%.
I already tried to use this:

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
```

But it's not working.

How can I avoid this?

**UPDATE 1:**

It seems that setCancelable(false) works fine. Thanks you very much for your answers but when the downloading long-lasting and the user decides to abandon it'll be impossible because I already deactivated the back keyCode:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

How can I figure this out?

Comment: Are you using AlertDialog?

Comment: Are you sure ? Can you show us some code?

Comment: have You tried setCancelable?

Comment: @zim my edit may help with your update.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Use `dialog.setCancelable(false);`

Example :

```
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(WiFiFinderActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("please wait...");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: `dialog.setCancelable(false);` is sufficient. While `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` ONLY prevents user from dismissing the dialog when he clicks anywhere else on the screen, the former ALSO prevents user from dismissing the dialog when he clicks the back button. Hence, you don't need to declare both.

Answer (score 11):

You dont wanna use this Override function.. You just set

```
final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(dialogactivity.this);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this line

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

or

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

as per your reqirement

Answer (score 1):

Try `myDialog.setCancelable(false);`. I'm not sure if a Progress Dialog has that method same as a AertDialog, but it may be worth a try.

Edit (to add for your update): Try using the following:

```
myDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //do your canceling stuff here
        }
    });
```

Also are you doing this in an AlertDialog or are you using AlertDialog.Builder?

IF you are useing AlertDialog.Builder you should use the following:

```
AlertDialog myProgressDialog = myDialog.create();
myProgressDialog.show();
```

Then you should be able to use `myProgressDialog.dismiss();` in your NegativeButton onClick.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your progress dialog:

```
progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method in your progress dialog :
This code will work fine.

```
 progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - what does that method do, and why should one use it?