# How can I avoid dismissing my AlertDialog.Builder dialog when the user touch the screen?

Tags: android

I'm working on an android project which a custom alert dialog, 
it has one textview and Button.

```
edt.setText("Enter Comment");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    CameraActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Enter your Comment");
            lnrt.addView(edt);
            builder.setView(lnrt);

            builder.setNegativeButton("SUBMIT", new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    edText = edt.getText().toString();
                    new upDb(2).execute();
                }
            });

            builder.create();
            builder.show();
```

when i touch out side dialog its getting hide, how to avoid this?
please help me.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15432562/870459, there is your anwser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I avoid dismissing my progress dialog when the user touch the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432476/how-can-i-avoid-dismissing-my-progress-dialog-when-the-user-touch-the-screen)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try

```
builder.setCancelable(false);
```

before you show the window, it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one...

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
...
...
alert.setCancelable(false);
final AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will prevent your dialog from closing when user touches area outside dialog:

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: 'AlertDialog' do not has the method.