# Disable click on Progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

i am trying to disable the touch while running progress bar on screen.Below code(getwindow) is not working. can anyone please help.

Using:

```
@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Doing something, please wait.");
            dialog.show();
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        }
```

Comment: do you mean that you want to dispose the progress bar when the background task finishes, and not when the user clicks outside the progress bar dialog?

Comment: yes, while progress bar is running i was to stop user touch. the problem is, progress bar is gone if i am touching anywhere on the screen

Answer (score 1):

seems like you want to set dialog **not Cancelable**
*just set property of dialog*

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `dialog.setCancelable(false);`

please refer to the following answer:

> [How to avoid dismissing my progress dialog when the user touches the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432476/how-to-avoid-dismissing-my-progress-dialog-when-the-user-touches-the-screen)