# progressDIalog.setCancelable(false) not working, dismiss on touch

Tags: android

I have a progress dialog that shows up when i am fetching some jSON data online. i want it to retain on screen until fetch is complete. however it disappears when user touches somewhere. how can i prevent this?

I have tried: [How to avoid dismissing my progress dialog when the user touches the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432476/how-to-avoid-dismissing-my-progress-dialog-when-the-user-touches-the-screen) and a few others.

However, none of them could solve my problem. i have tried getRetainInstance in place of false, still doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
public class Login extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    parentHolder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    downloadJSON(url);
    return parentHolder;
}

private void downloadJSON(final String urlWebService) {
    class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
            this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
            this.dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            try {
                loadIntoListView(s);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            // some code
        }
    }
}

private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
    // Some code
}
}
```

Comment: I apologize. i'll keep in mind that now.

Comment: I only use `this.dialog.setCancelable(false)` and it work fine for me. Have you tried by removing `this.dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`?

Comment: tried removing, still no luck! @JayeshBabu